# Simple example regarding how to parse data from html output using lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

Im converting some python scripts that uses regex to exract contents from a html output to libxml2, but since im starting at this, a little help would be apreciated.

how i can extract the values from "working directory" , "Packages/Updates" , and "Java Data Model" of the example bellow using lxml?

```
<tr>
  <script>writeTD("row");</script>
  <td class="oddrow"><nobr>Working Dir</nobr></td>
  <script>writeTD("rowdata-l");</script>
  <td class="oddrowdata-l">/serves/test_servers</td>
</tr> 
<script>swapRows();</script>
<tr>
  <script>writeTD("row");</script>
  <td class="evenrow"><nobr>Packages/Updates</nobr></td>
  <script>writeTD("rowdata-l");</script>
  <td class="evenrowdata-l"><a href="updates.dsp">View</a></td>
</tr> 
<script>swapRows();</script>
<tr>
  <script>writeTD("row");</script>
  <td class="oddrow"><nobr>Java Data Model</nobr></td>
  <script>writeTD("rowdata-l");</script>
  <td class="oddrowdata-l">64-bit</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the HTML you posted as `content`,

```
import lxml.html as LH
doc = LH.fromstring(content)
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath('//td'))    
for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
    if td in ("Working Dir", "Java Data Model"):
        print(td,val)
```

yields

```
('Working Dir', '/serves/test_servers')
('Java Data Model', '64-bit')
```

---

This line does most of the work:

```
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath('//td'))
```

It uses the `xpath()` method to search for all `<td>` tags. It uses the `text_content()` method to extract the associated text.

`zip(*[tds]*2)` is the [grouper idiom](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) to iterate over `tds` in pairs:

```
for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
    print(td,val)
```

Note that this assumes that `<td>` labels and values follow each other alternately.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! Thanks a lot,

But now, how i could to do a selective extraction? As an example, if i want to extract only "working directory"  and "Java Data Model"  ?

Comment: You could use something like `if td in ("Working Dir", "Java Data Model")`. I've edited the post to show what I mean.